# 504 after 120 seconds

Tags: php, file-get-contents, http-status-code-504

I have this code

```
$url="site.com";//~
$opts=array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept: */*i\r\n".
              "User-Agent: Your application name\r\n",
        "ignore_errors" => true,
        "timeout" => 1800
    ),
    "ssl"=>array(
        "allow_self_signed"=>true,
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    )
);
$page = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($opts));
...
...
```

If *$url* (web page) is small size - script works well.

But when the size is large, and the running time begins to exceed 120 seconds -

process is going to abort and displayed 504 ERROR.

### --

At the beginning of the script I add:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',18000);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout',18000);
ignore_user_abort(true);
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

In *ini.php* i add following:

```
max_execution_time = 18000;
max_input_time = 18000;
```

But nothing helps.

**Question:** How can i extend script execution time - more than 120 seconds ?

**PS:** All of the above (*max_execution_time*, ...) changed according to the specified intagers (as seen by *phpinfo()*). But parameters *realpath_cache_size* and *realpath_cache_ttl* (in *phpinfo()* written that equals 120) doesn't change. Maybe a problem on this ?

Comment: Are you running this through Nginx? Also, `realpath_cache_size` doesn't have anything to do with execution time.

Comment: No, through Apache.

Comment: But realpath_cache_ttl mayby do something http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.realpath-cache-ttl

Comment: No, that's something completely different. It doesn't have anything to do with execution timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running for as long as you set it ,
Infact if you simply add to the top of your code

```
       set_time_limit(0);
```

It's won't stop till it's end,
However if you want to keep waiting for the  output then you need to set the Apache2 timeout limit, and also your browser timeout limit.

Comment: I forgot to write about set_time_limit (0), I tried it too.

Comment: Apache default timeout limit is 300 sec.http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout , and my browser timeout limit also equal 300 https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/socket/client_socket_pool.cc?sq=package:chromium&l=25